# How to feed uploaded data by using 'fileInput' function to plot a ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly

I am trying to develop a `shiny app` in which I am giving the user an option to upload a data file (CSV or txt). Then I want to render a `ggplot` or `plotly` from this data. There are various columns in that dataset. So, I need to render various Plots, and they are to be rendered by the user selecting the columns in that dataset to be x-axis data and y-axis data. I have provided options to the user to select the data column for x and y axes. But, when I feed the data columns selected by the user for plotting, the output does not show any graph.

code for my plot:

```
df <- mtcars
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
geom_point(aes(color='blue'))
```

should I use `aes` or `aes_string` to render the columns from the uploaded data?

Comment: Here is my code:

Comment: please add your code in the question

Comment: I am trying to add my code in the question but it is showing me this error: Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Comment: 3 methods to add code easily: (1) for in-line stuff, use the [ ` ] character to surround the text (without the brackets).  (2) to start typing code, use CTRL+K and go for block code.  New lines can be made with SHIFT+ENTER and as the note says, indent code within that with 4 spaces to be nice to us.  (3) Paste a bunch of text from your code, then select it all and use CTRL+K to turn it all into block code.  From there, please just make sure to format nicely.  It will already be indented, but likely you'll want to add new lines and indent a bit to make it easier to read.

Comment: Now its showing me this error: "Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code)."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this exact issue for a while trying to show a plot in shiny.  Consider that you are likely having the user choose a `selectInput` drop down for column selection, right?  That is going to send a string (chr) to your `ggplot` functions.

Normally, you use `aes()` to choose aesthetics, but that won't work with strings.  For that, you need `aes_string()`.  It's used exactly the same way as `aes()`, but all calls are character strings.  [See documentation for information](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/1.0.0/topics/aes_string).

So if your `ggplot` call was:

```
ggplot(myData, aes(x=something, y=somethingElse)) +
    geom_point(aes(color=prettyColors))
```

Where columns in your dataset `myData` were "something", "somethingElse" and "prettyColors", then using `aes_string()`, you create the same plot using:

```
ggplot(myData, aes_string(x="something", y="somethingElse")) +
    geom_point(aes_string(color="prettyColors"))
```

Comment: That was really helpful, it worked with ggplot, now can you tell me how can I do the same for plotly?

Comment: Sorry - have not used `plotly` before :(